# JavaScript: Stop while loop when an event occurs

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, dom-events, addeventlistener

I want a while loop to stop when the "load" event occurs.

This executes a while loop after the event occurs:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    while (...) {...}
});
```

I wish to do this in pure JavaScript (not using jQuery or any other library).

("load" event: the page is fully loaded; `document.readyState == "complete"`: the page is not fully loaded.)

Comment: Wat? Wat are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'd suggest to use events instead of loop until something occurs. It could be too heavy or even crash the whole page. But the ways of stopping a loop are with `break` or with a propper condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    while (document.readyState !== "complete") {
     //do Whatever
     }
});
```

Comment: This executes the while loop after the load event occurs, not before.